# Estrutura em "arvore", como iterar sobre ela?

Tags: javascript, react, imutabilidade

Observem a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando clonar uma pagina utilizando o conceitos do immutable.

Cada pagina tem algumas características e a característica que devo preparar antes de salvar a pagina no estado(state) é a "localId"

Ao clicar no link "clone" o seguinte código é chamado:

```
export const clonePageByLocalId = (state:any, sourcePageLocalId:string, position:number) => {

  // get the source page and clone it
  let sourcePageNode = getPageByLocalId( state, sourcePageLocalId )
  sourcePageNode = sourcePageNode.set('localId', v4() )

  let sourcePageNodeModify = prepareLocalId(sourcePageNode )

  let sourcePageNodeModify = sourcePageNodeModify.set('title', sourcePageNodeModify.get('title') +  '(clone)');
  sourcePageNodeModify = sourcePageNodeModify.set('title', sourcePageNodeModify.get('title') +  '(clone)');

  // ---> insert the cloned page into new location
  const newState = insertPage(state, sourcePageLocalId, position + 1, sourcePageNodeModify )

  return newState
}
```

Preparar os localIds:

```
const prepareLocalId = (sourcePageNode:any) => {

let sourcePageNodeModify = sourcePageNode.set('localId', v4() )

if ( sourcePageNodeModify.get('pages') && sourcePageNodeModify.get('pages').size > 0) {

sourcePageNodeModify.get('pages').forEach(function (page) {

    prepareLocalId( page )
});
}
return sourcePageNode
}
```

O clone está acontecendo, porem ao clicar na "pagina 2 (clone)" e tentar expandir a pagina "Page Two B" quem sofre efeito é a "pagina 2".
Isso está acontecendo por que o localId não está sendo alterado de fato.

Galera, poderia me ajudar em encontrar um caminho melhor que eu possa iterar sobre as paginas e setar um valor em sua propriedade "localId"?.

Abraços.

Comment: Olá galera.
Consegui encontrar uma maneira de realizar essa iteração.

Answer (score 0):

Sou novo em desenvolvimento com react, redux, immutable e etc. Depois de ler diversos artigos sobre a estrutura do immutable encontrei uma solução.

Foi o seguinte:

O primeiro ponto foi transformar uma estrutura immutable em um objeto js, como esse objeto não está associado a um estado, podemos realizar as modificações sem preocupações.

Apos realizar as modificações foi preciso retornar a estrutura em JS para o formato immutable.

Assim foi possível inserir a nova pagina no estado e retornar esse novo estado.

No final, o codigo ficou da seguinte forma:

```
export const clonePageByLocalId = (state:any, sourcePageLocalId:string, position:number) => {

// get the source page and clone it
let sourcePageNode = getPageByLocalId( state, sourcePageLocalId )

let sourcePageNodeModify = setupEditingPages( sourcePageNode.toJS() )

sourcePageNodeModify.title =  sourcePageNodeModify.title + ' (clone)'

// ---> insert the cloned page into new location
const newState = insertPage(state, sourcePageLocalId, position + 1, fromJS(sourcePageNodeModify) )

return newState
}
```

Interação recursiva

```
const setupEditingPages = (page:any) => {
   page.localId = v4()
   page.collapsed = true
   if ( page.pages && page.pages.length > 0 ) {
      for(let i = 0; i < page.pages.length; i++) {
        page.pages[i] = setupEditingPages(page.pages[i])
     }
   }

  return page
}
```

Esse projeto em que estou trabalhando é um projeto OpenSource que está disponível no https://github.com/omar331/evoluttree
Caso alguém queira dar uma olhada e entender melhor do que se trata fique a vontade.

Abraços.